# Pandoc-generated lstinline in index

Tags: listings, memoir, indexing, pandoc, makeindex

I'm generating a large document using Pandoc, and I'd like to use inline code in my index keys. Pandoc generates `\passthrough{\lstinline!foo!}` for these inline code fragments, and they don't seem to work in the index.

Here's an example document:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand{\passthrough}[1]{#1}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\passthrough{\lstinline!Code formatting!} outside index works.
\index{NAND gate@{\passthrough{\lstinline!NAND!} gate}}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

This fails with:

```
Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]
system returned with code 256

(_build/book.ind)
Runaway argument?
NAND \subsubitem  gate}, 1^^M^^M\end{theindex}^^M
! File ended while scanning use of \lst@temp.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.16 \end
         {document}
?
```

**Were it not for Pandoc**, I could escape the bangs with double-quotes, since this seems to work:

```
\index{NAND gate@\passthrough{\lstinline"!NAND"!} gate}
```

However, this is, frankly, insane syntax, since it requires not *wrapping* in double quotes (which I could easily do in a custom Pandoc filter), but *prefixing* each `!` individually with a `"`. I'm not convinced that is possible to do with a Pandoc filter.

I should add that I have absolutely zero preference for what indexing system to use, so if there is a better fit for this use case than `imakeidx`, I am all ears.